# laravel подскажите недочеты

Tags: php, laravel, инспекция-кода

Сам новичок, изучаю ларавел пару недель ) Вот сделал простенький crud, подскажите недочеты )

Контроллер:

```
public function index()
    {
        $allSpec = Specialization::all();
        return view('specialization.index',['specializations' => $allSpec]);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('specialization.create',['specializations' => Specialization::all()]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Specialization $specialization)
    {
        $specialization->fill($request->all())->save();
        return redirect()->route('specialization');
    }


    public function show($slug, Specialization $specializationModel)
    {
        $specialization = $specializationModel->getOne($slug);
        if($specialization->parentid !== 0) {
        $specialization->parent = $specializationModel->getParentName($specialization->parentid);
        }

        return view('specialization.show', ['specialization' => $specialization]);
    }


    public function edit($slug, Specialization $specializationModel, Request $request) 
    {

        $specialization = $specializationModel->getOne($slug);
        $specializations = Specialization::where('id', '!=' ,$specialization->id);
        return view('specialization.edit', ['specialization'=>$specialization,'specs' => $specializations]);
    }

    public function update($slug,Specialization $specialization)
    {

        $input = Input::except('_method', '_token');
        $specialization->where('slug',$slug)->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('specialization');
    }
```

Роутер:

```
Route::get('/specializations', ['as' => 'specialization', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@index']);
Route::get('/specializations/create', ['as' => 'specialization.create', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@create']);
Route::post('/specializations/create', ['as' => 'specialization.store', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@store']);
Route::get('/specializations/{slug}', ['as' => 'specialization.show', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@show']);
Route::get('/specializations/{slug}/edit', ['as' => 'specialization.edit', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@edit']);
Route::put('/specializations/{slug}/edit', ['as' => 'specialization.put', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@update']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Роутер посоветовал бы написать след. вида, так как он может расти и будет в дальнейшем тяжело его поддерживать

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'specializations'], function () {

     Route::get('/', ['as' => 'specialization', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@index']);

     Route::group(['prefix' => 'create'], function () {
           Route::get('/', ['as' => 'specialization.create', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@create']);
           Route::post('/', ['as' => 'specialization.store', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@store']);
     });

     Route::group(['prefix' => '{slug}'], function () {
           Route::get('/', ['as' => 'specialization.show', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@show']);
           Route::get('/edit', ['as' => 'specialization.edit', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@edit']);
           Route::put('/edit', ['as' => 'specialization.put', 'uses' => 'SpecializationController@update']);
     });  
});
```

По контроллеру, прям по laravel, сказать почти нечего, при добавлении и изменении используй валидатор:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

В ларавел же реализованные `Route::resource()` для CRUD, почитай доку заморскую (хотя и в русской по-моему тоже все есть .